# C++ Sorting an array by values from another

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stl

I'm trying to sort vector(deque(int)) population by order of distances (which is double array).

```
sort(population.begin(), population.end(), [&distance](size_t i1, size_t i2) { return distance[i1] < distance[i2]; });
```

I have no idea how to fix it. The way it is written above, the "cannot convert size_t into deque(int) etc..." error occurs.

Comment: show the definition of `population` and `distance`.

Comment: without knowing `population` it is impossible to comment on it

Comment: vector<deque<int>> population;
double *distance = new double[population.size()];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found myself a simple solution:
I matched distance and population into structure:

```
struct popWithDist{
deque<int> *population;
double distace;
};
```

Then it was very easy to sort it:

```
    vector<popWithDist> pwd;

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPopulation; i++){
        pwd.push_back({ &population[i], getWholeDist(population[i]) });
    }
    //Sorting population by distance order:
    sort(pwd.begin(), pwd.end(), [](popWithDist i1, popWithDist i2) { return i1.distace < i2.distace; });

    for (int i = 0; i < population.size(); i++){
        population[i] = *pwd[i].population;
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort` expects a binary operator which is able to compare two elements of the same type of the one specified by the iterators passed.

In your case `decltype(population)::value_type != size_t` so the lambda can't be used as a correct comparator.

It should be something like, let `T` be your population element:

```
vector<T> population;
sort(population.begin(), population.end(), [&distance](const T& i1, const T& i2) { ... });
```

Comment: But how to define the comparator now? Distance[0] is summary distance of population[0].